# Will a table with an int primary key outperform its uid equivalent?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a legacy Sql Server database which uses UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and am considering performance. If I have two tables, idencial except for the Identity column, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [uidExampleTable] (
    [exampleUid]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT [DF_uidExampleTable_uid] DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [name]            VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [createdDate]     DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_uidExampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([exampleUid] ASC));

CREATE TABLE [intExampleTable] (
    [exampleIntId]    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]            VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [createdDate]     DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_intExampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([[exampleIntId] ASC));
```

And I fill these tables with, say, ten million rows each, then perform a select on each:

`Select top 20 * from uidExampleTable order by createdDate desc`

`Select top 20 * from intExampleTable order by createdDate desc`

Would you expect the second query on intExampleTable to return results more quickly?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the index to help, but what makes you think the UID table doesn't have an index?

Comment: For those queries, the `int` pk * might * be faster only because it's smaller (int are 4 bytes vs 16 for uuids). And remember that when adding not-clustered indices to a clustered indexed table, the rows are referenced by pk, so your secondary indices will also be bigger with a uuid pk.

Comment: A heap is a table without a clustered key. The type of your clustered key does not matter

Comment: @jonaglon What decides whether or not a table has a key is adding the `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([exampleUid] ASC))` command. You could forget to do this with an `int` key, too.

Comment: Also: INSERT statements would be slower with the UID. With an IDENTITY, the inserts are naturally already in primary key order, but with a UID it's more random, where you usually need to insert into the middle of a page somewhere.  You can offset this a bit by changing the `FILL FACTOR` for your pages, but that comes at the cost of needing more pages for the table. This is also why we also have [sequential UIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql).

Comment: Question updated to be less specific, I've realised I don't really understand what it means to primary key cluster using a uniqueidentifier. The question essentially remains the same.

Comment: I've rolled this stuff up into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tables have an index. Whether or not there is an index on the table is determined by the `PRIMARY KEY` directive, rather than the type of the key field.

However, these indexes won't help those queries for either table.

There are still some performance differences, though. The `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (hereafter UID, because I'm lazy) adds an extra 12 bytes for each row. Assuming the average `name` length is 10 characters out of a possible 50, that should work out to 38 bytes per row<sup>*</sup> on average for the `int` table  and 50 bytes per row on average for the `UID` table, which is more than a 30% increase in row size.

So yes, that can make a difference over 10 million records. Keep in mind, though, for many tables you'll have a lot more data in the table, and the relative difference starts to diminish as the width of the table increases.

The other place you'll have a performance difference is `INSERT` statements. With an `IDENTITY` column, an `INSERT` is naturally already in primary key order and new records are simply appended to the end of the last page (or the beginning of a new page, if the last page was full). A `UID`, though, is more random, where you usually need to insert into the middle of a page somewhere. You can offset this a bit by changing the [`FILL FACTOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15) for your index, but that comes at the cost of needing more pages. This is one reason we also have [sequential UIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql).

Even so, these differences tend to be small compared to other factors. Sometimes they can be important, but you generally need to **measure your system's performance** first to know for sure.

For example, for this query, rather than worrying about the UID vs INT for the key, you can really improve things by adding a descending index for the `createdDate` column. Definitely if you know you could have more than 4 billion rows, or it could be dangerous if people could guess an ID to get a valid record, don't let a little bit of performance out weigh those concerns.

---

<sub>* 14 bytes row overhead + 4 bytes int ID + 2 bytes varchar overhead + 10 bytes varchar data + 8 bytes datetime = 38 bytes total</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will, except when you have 1,000’s of inserts per second and your storage cannot handle it, then you will get contention for the writes.